# How can it be ensured that a child record is of same record type as of its parent object?

Tags: record-type, relationships

I have a parent and child relationship among objects,both having record types A & B?

I want to ensure that Parent record of A record type should be able to create Child record of A record type only.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in few ways:

- URL hack on child creation button
- override create/edit page of child record
- create validation rule to enforce matching Record Types

I think it would be best to combine those solutions.
Best approach depends on your environment settings.